# How to sleep while sore

Tags: sleep

So this question comes as I lie in bed, legs aching, incapable of falling asleep. I worked out in the evening today since I couldn't get to the gym in the morning, and had a successful deadlift and squat session. My legs still hurt, however, and it's noticeable enough that I can't get comfortable in bed. Any suggestions for how to get to sleep after an evening workout?

Comment: You could consider using a [foam roller](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/using-a-foam-roller).  This q/a about [muscle soreness](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11643/my-legs-still-ache-3-4-days-after-legs-day/11687#11687) may give additional ideas.

Comment: I've had pretty good luck with melatonin. You really don't need much; 1g-3g taken a couple of hours before you want to go to sleep has been really beneficial. The stuff is cheap, well researched, and not habit forming unless you're using it constantly for a really long amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that there's a secret formula, but, I tend to reach for ice or heat and an NSAID.  But, then again, I'm 50+ !  The point is, treat it like an injury.  A hard workout is like receiving micro trauma to the muscles.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome back to Leg workouts.  Especially among former athletes and former lifters who take some time off it is extremely easy to overdo your first few (leg) workouts.

After about 10 workouts you will notice that this post workout suffering will be much more manageable.

Some ideas
Hot and Cold Tubs right after a workout will help out greatly
Prescription and Over the Counter drugs may help in the short term.

Comment: I'm not getting back into leg workouts; I've been doing them consistently for a while. Usually I do them in the morning, and so I just deal with being sore at work, sleeping is different though. Also I took Motrin and it didn't help.